# Сложная форма UIView (или sprite)

Tags: ios, swift, spritekit, uiview

Есть матрица NxM, стоящая из кастомных UIView. На основании этой матрицы, на экране строятся фигуры типа

[image: исходный]

Строятся через

```html
let width = gridView.frame.width / CGFloat(numberOfRows)
let height = gridView.frame.height / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
  for i in 0..<numberOfRows {
    for j in 0..<numberOfColumns {
      let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(i)*width, y: CGFloat(j)*height, width: width, height: height))
       gridView.addSubview(myView)
    }
}
```

Каким образом объединить эти маленькие view в один, чтоб можно было наложить градиент? 
Вот в такой [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И далее, при "стыковке" с такими же фигурами, объединять уже их для наложения общего градиента (что-то похожее на тетрис)

Comment: Приведенный отрывок кода строит сплошную матрицу, без исключений отдельных элементов (а не как у вас на рисунке, где исключен один элемент во втором ряду). Не могли бы привести код, на основе которого исключается тот или иной элемент?

Comment: myView.backgroundColor = gridArray[i][j] вот и нужно фигуры одного цвета объединить

Answer (score 0):

Лучше сделать это не через много маленьких UIView, а через один, который уже нужной формы. Рисуйте его через Core Graphics, переопределив метод draw. Там же можно покрасить получившуюся фигуру любой сложности в любой цвет, в том виде используя градиент.

Comment: Так в этом и вопрос. Каким образом, на основании матрицы нарисовать такую View? Или более сложный случай, если эта View должна иметь отверстие в середине, например.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле вопрос у вас достаточно объемный - рисование фигур, определение контуров, заливка градиентом, определение столкновений, объединение фигур, и по-хорошему его надо бы разделить.

Набросал в онлайн-компиляторе (в котором почему-то нет поддержки некоторых свойств `CGRect`, поэтому добавил хелперы) черновой класс для построения фигур как указано выше, а также вычисления их границ для последующей отрисовки по точкам например с помощью методов `UIBezierPath` (`move(to:)`, `addLine(to:)`). Посмотрите, если будут вопросы, задавайте, вопросы заливки и столкновений пока оставим за рамками, если будет время, можно и это реализовать.

```
import Foundation

class GridBuilder {

    struct Line: Equatable {

        enum Side {
            case l, t, r, b
        }

        var p1: CGPoint
        var p2: CGPoint
        var side: Side

        static func == (l: Line, r: Line) -> Bool {
            return l.p1 == r.p1 && l.p2 == r.p2 && l.side == r.side 
        }
    }

    struct GridRect: Equatable {
        var rect: CGRect
        var isHole = false

        static func == (l: GridRect, r: GridRect) -> Bool {
            return l.rect == r.rect && l.isHole == r.isHole
        }
    }

    struct Grid {
        var rects: [GridRect]
        var holeRects: [GridRect]
        var outlinePoints: [CGPoint]
        var holesPoints: [[CGPoint]]
    }

    private static func c(_ r:CGRect) -> CGPoint { 
        return CGPoint(x: r.origin.x + r.size.width / 2, y: r.origin.y + r.size.height / 2)
    }

    private static func rectToPoints(_ r: CGRect) -> [CGPoint] {
        return [
            r.origin, 
            CGPoint(x: r.origin.x + r.size.width, y: r.origin.y),
            CGPoint(x: r.origin.x + r.size.width, y: r.origin.y + r.size.height),
            CGPoint(x: r.origin.x, y: r.origin.y + r.size.height)
            ]
    }

    private static func contains(_ r: CGRect, _ p: CGPoint) -> Bool {
        return p.x > r.origin.x && p.x < r.origin.x + r.size.width && p.y > r.origin.y && p.y < r.origin.y + r.size.height
    } 

    private static func append(_ array: inout [CGPoint], _ p: CGPoint) {
        if !array.contains(p) {
            array.append(p)
        }
    }

    private static func sortLines(_ srcArray: [Line], _ dstArray: inout [Line], _ line: Line) {

        if dstArray.count == srcArray.count {
            return
        }

        if dstArray.count == 0 {
            dstArray.append(line)
            sortLines(srcArray, &dstArray, line)
        }

        for l in srcArray {

            if l == line {
                continue
            }

            if l.p1 == line.p2 && !dstArray.contains(l) {
                dstArray.append(l)
                sortLines(srcArray, &dstArray, l)
            }
        }
    }

    public static func createGrid(
        width: CGFloat, 
        height: CGFloat,
        rowsCount: Int,
        columnsCount: Int,
        exclusions: [Int]) -> Grid {

            let w = width
            let h = height
            let rows = rowsCount
            let cols = columnsCount
            let elW = w / CGFloat(cols) 
            let elH = h / CGFloat(rows) 
            let ex = exclusions 
            var count = 0
            var rects = [GridRect]()
            var holeRects = [GridRect]()
            var lines = [Line]()

            for i in 0..<cols { 
                for j in 0..<rows { 

                let r = CGRect(x: CGFloat(i)*elW, y: CGFloat(j)*elH, width: elW, height: elH)
                rects.append(GridRect(rect: r, isHole: ex.contains(count)))

                count += 1 
                }
            }

            print("rects")
            for r in rects {
                print(r)
            }

            for r1 in rects { 
             var l = true
             var t = true
             var r = true
             var b = true

             for r2 in rects {
              if r1 == r2 {
               continue  
              }

              if l { 
               var p = c(r1.rect)
               p.x -= r1.rect.size.width
               l = !contains(r2.rect, p)
              }

              if t {
               var p = c(r1.rect)
               p.y -= r1.rect.size.height
               t = !contains(r2.rect, p) 
              }

              if r {
               var p = c(r1.rect)
               p.x += r1.rect.size.width
               r = !contains(r2.rect, p) 
              }

              if b {
               var p = c(r1.rect)
               p.y += r1.rect.size.height
               b = !contains(r2.rect, p) 
              }

             }

             print(l, t, r, b) 

             if r1.isHole && !l && !t && !r && !b {
                 holeRects.append(r1)
             } else {
                 if l {
                lines.append(Line(
                    p1: CGPoint(x: r1.rect.origin.x, y: r1.rect.origin.y + r1.rect.size.height), 
                    p2: CGPoint(x: r1.rect.origin.x, y: r1.rect.origin.y), side: .l))
             } 

             if t { 
                lines.append(Line(
                    p1: CGPoint(x: r1.rect.origin.x, y: r1.rect.origin.y), 
                    p2: CGPoint(x: r1.rect.origin.x + r1.rect.size.width, y: r1.rect.origin.y), side: .t))
             }

             if r { 
                lines.append(Line(
                    p1: CGPoint(x: r1.rect.origin.x + r1.rect.size.width, y: r1.rect.origin.y), 
                    p2: CGPoint(x: r1.rect.origin.x + r1.rect.size.width, y: r1.rect.origin.y + r1.rect.size.height), side: .r))
             } 

             if b {
                lines.append(Line(
                    p1: CGPoint(x: r1.rect.origin.x + r1.rect.size.width, y: r1.rect.origin.y + r1.rect.size.height), 
                    p2: CGPoint(x: r1.rect.origin.x, y: r1.rect.origin.y + r1.rect.size.height), side: .b))
             }
             }

            }

            var lines2 = [Line]()
            sortLines(lines, &lines2, lines[0])
            let outlinePoints = lines2.map{$0.p1}

            for i in 0..<outlinePoints.count {
                print(i + 1, outlinePoints[i])
            }

            let holesPoints = holeRects.map{rectToPoints($0.rect)}
            print("holes", holesPoints)

            return Grid(rects: rects, holeRects: holeRects, outlinePoints: outlinePoints, holesPoints: holesPoints)

        }

}

let grid = GridBuilder.createGrid(width: 10, height: 10, rowsCount: 3, columnsCount: 3, exclusions: [4])
```